# search for ALL DNS TXT records of a domain and subdomains

Tags: dns, subdomain, spf, dkim, dig

There is a way to retrieve ALL (TXT) entries about DNS records of a domain (and subdomains) ?

My goal is to verify the configuration of my domain: www.rosposhop.com
where I correctly set multiple SPF and DKIM records for some subdomains

```
rosposhop.com
md.rosposhop.com (SPF+DKIM)
mg.rosposhop.com (SPF+DKIM)
```

(so I have a total of 5 TXT items)

Now, if I ask with `dig` or `host -a`, I got only the first TXT item, instead I was expected to have the complete list of TXT items.

Whre I'm wrong ?

```
$ dig  rosposhop.com TXT


; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.1-Ubuntu <<>> rosposhop.com TXT
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 14774
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;rosposhop.com.                 IN      TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
rosposhop.com.          2362    IN      TXT     "google-site-verification=udcP944OqB1PldDn1ML"

;; Query time: 65 msec
;; SERVER: ***********
;; WHEN: Sat Dec 27 09:10:43 CET 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 123
```

BTW, if I ask puntually for a SUBdomain, now I got again only the first entry:

```
$ dig  md.rosposhop.com TXT
```

return:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
md.rosposhop.com.       2223    IN      TXT     "v=spf1 include:spf.man*******"
```

again I don't get the DKIM info.
It's a security/permissions topic ?
sorry for my DNS-ignorance.

thanks
giorgio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The approach of making a single DNS query to get all that information in one fell swoop is misguided.  It assumes that the data for a single zone is a) static and b) managed by a single name server.  DNS imposes no such limitations on zone data.

Both SPF and DKIM (and DMARC, if you want to throw that in the mix) use TXT records on specific domains.  There is no need to get all the TXT records for a domain and its subdomains to view the relevant configuration.

If you want to get the SPF and DKIM information, just query the appropriate domains.  Assuming you're doing Return-Path domains and DKIM signatures on `md.rosposhop.com` and `mg.rosposhop.com` then you should be interested in TXT records on

1. `md.rosposhop.com` - SPF
2. `mg.rosposhop.com` - SPF
3. `(selector)._domainkey.md.rosposhop.com` - DKIM
4. `(selector)._domainkey.mg.rosposhop.com` - DKIM

where (selector) is the selector you're using for that DKIM record.  You may have more than one selector for each of `md.rosposhop.com` and `mg.rosposhop.com` domains.  TXT records on other domains are irrelevant.

Comment: thanks Peter. I verified and you are fully right. I selected your answer.

Comment: Yes but what if the selector is unknown.
I would have assumed this was the intent of the question, what selectors are in play and then once getting those they can each be queried.

Answer (score 2):

To get all the records of a domain, you use an `AXFR` request to perform a zone transfer. This must be sent to one of the authoritive servers for the domain:

```
dig rosposhop.com axfr @ns52.domaincontrol.com
```

However, most DNS servers restrict zone transfers for security reasons. Normally, only the master server allows zone transfers, and only to the known slave servers. The `domaincontrol.com` servers don't allow zone transfers, so you'll get an error if you try this.

Comment: in facts with AXFR I got: `;; communications error to 208.109.255.26#53: end of file`

Comment: I know. I said they don't allow zone transfers.

Answer (score 0):

There are cases where you have multiple TXT entries with the same DNS entry. For example, letsencrypt key verification for wildcards and base DNS name requires two _acme_challenge TXT entries with different keys for the same domain name, as described here: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/multiple-challenges-when-requesting-wildcard-certificate-for-3-domains/66783.